# How can I delete all files in a folder with names that longer than X?

Tags: 20.04, bash

I have a folder with 1000s of files in that are named 23123 123r3883 3929388394j f38238d etc. I need to remove all the files that have a name length > 9. How can I do this?

Comment: Does it have to be bash? zsh has some handy glob qualifiers for this kind of thing

Comment: please do use google. https://superuser.com/a/702461/276585  and no I am not going to steal fossie's answer there :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match filenames that consist of at least 10 characters using a simple glob expression `??????????*`. So provided the number of files is not too long, you could use

```
echo rm -- ??????????*
```

For longer file lists, you could break the names up using `xargs`:

```
printf '%s\0' -- ??????????* | xargs -r0 echo rm
```

If you switch from `bash` to `zsh`, you could make use of *glob qualifiers* to test the length of each filename (passed via the `REPLY` variable). One advantage is that you can easily add other qualifiers like `N` (equivalent of the bash shell's `nullglob`) and `.` (which limits the results to plain files):

```
echo rm -- *(.Ne:'[[ $#REPLY -gt 9 ]]':)
```

or

```
print -rNC1 -- *(.Ne:'[[ $#REPLY -gt 9 ]]':) | xargs -r0 echo rm
```

To do the equivalent in bash would likely require a loop, like

```
for f in *; do
  [[ -f $f && $#f -gt 9 ]] && echo rm -- "$f"
done
```

**Remove the `echo` once you are satisfied that the right files are being matched**.

Comment: Or `find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "?????????*" -delete`